# Can you use explicit constructors with designated initializers?

Tags: c++, c++20

In the code below, is the initialization of member `b` legal?

```
class B {
    public:
        explicit B(int) {}
};

struct A {
    B b;
};

class C {
 public:
    C() : a{.b{33}} {}

    A a;
};
```

Compiling with the latest version of gcc gives this error ([wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pCr65PktjdGqKVAo))

```
prog.cc: In constructor 'C::C()':
prog.cc:12:11: error: converting to 'B' from initializer list would use explicit constructor 'B::B(int)'
   12 |     C() : a{.b{33}} {}
      |           ^~~~~~~~~
```

But the latest version of clang compiles the code fine ([wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AkuAXg8Gdl4iCoXg))

Which compiler is correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a gcc bug (submitted [99566](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99566)).

The rule, from [[dcl.init.aggr]/4.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#4.2), is:

> Otherwise, the element is copy-initialized from the corresponding initializer-clause or is initialized with the brace-or-equal-initializer of the corresponding designated-initializer-clause.

The element (`b`) should be initialized from the brace-or-equal-initializer (`{33}`). That's totally fine, that's not copy-initialization. gcc accepts `B b{33}`, the same kind of thing should happen here.

Comment: This was CWG2359.